# Save jqgrid table row when clicked outside table unless clicked on datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid table. One column is a datepicker column.

this code saves table cell when clicked elswhere.

`jQuery(document).on('focusout','[role="gridcell"] *', function(){
            jqGridTegevused.jqGrid('saveCell', row, col);
        })`

This is all good. But this code interrupts the work of datepicker. When i select date in datepicker it is not set to table cell.

How can i make it so that when i clik outside of table cell the cell is saved, unless i click on datepicker, because i need the datepiceker to finish its work first before saveing cell. And currently the focusout happens before datepickers onSelect. And if the date is added manually not with datepicker onSelect then it needs to save the cell in focusout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `relatedTarget` property of the `focusout` event to detect whether the user clicked inside of datepicker control or not. The outer div of the datepicker has class `ui-datepicker`. Thus your code could be fixed as

```
$(document).on('focusout','[role="gridcell"] *', function (e) {
    var p = jqGridTegevused.jqGrid("getGridParam");

    if ($(e.relatedTarget).closest('.ui-datepicker').length === 0) {
        // save editing cell only if the current click is not inside of Datepicker
        jqGridTegevused.jqGrid('saveCell', p.iRow, p.iCol);
    }
});
```

The next problem: the `focusout` will be triggered **only once** on focusout. You should write additional code inside of `onSelect` callback of the datepicker to force setting of the focus back to the input field to be able to save the cell later after the user will click outside of the grid *after choosing the date in the datepicker.

I thank that the usage of `$(document).on('focusout','[role="gridcell"] *', ...);` could be not perfect. You should test it carefully. Binding `focusout` of the input/select ... inside of `afterEditCell` seems to me better as `$(document).on('focusout','[role="gridcell"] *'`. See https://jsfiddle.net/7oLga5ze/ where I used

```
afterEditCell: function (rowid, nm, tmp, iRow, iCol) {
    var $grid = $(this);

    $(this.rows[iRow].cells[iCol])
        .find("input,textarea,select,button,object,*[tabindex]")
        .filter(":input:visible:not(:disabled)")
        .first()
        .on("focusout", function (e) {
            var p = $grid.jqGrid('getGridParam');

            if ($(e.relatedTarget).closest('.ui-datepicker').length === 0) {
                $grid.jqGrid('saveCell', p.iRow, p.iCol);
            }
        });
}
```

and I added setting focus on the input element inside of `onSelect` of the datepicker.

Comment: Hi Oleg! 5 years later, and your jsfiddle example is no longer working on the Chrome and Edge browsers. We had been using code similar to this for years with no issue, until just recently. Do you have any idea why or suggestions? I'm using version 104.0.5112.102 of Chrome. On Edge, your code works on version 103.0.1264.49, but fails on 104.1.1293.47